# How to go to the bottom of the file on startup in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, eof

I know this is completely unreasonable feature for a text editor to have, however, when I edit various files, I almost always have to do it at the end of the file.

Is there a feature in Notepad++ that will move the cursor, caret and focus to the bottom of the file?

Or perhaps open Notepad++ with a command-line parameter that forces cursor to the bottom

Comment: Record a macro (or Python script plugin) which does a File Open followed by `Ctrl`+`End`. Assign this to your favourite shortcut, such as `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`O`.

Comment: Since the answer is not / no longer "no", consider accepting [Gnubie's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/58928/how-to-go-to-the-bottom-of-the-file-on-startup-in-notepad/392348#392348) since it explicitly covers the command-line option you ask about.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No. But you have two options:

- Notepad++ is GNU. Get the sources, patch, build.
- Open the file, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl+End is reasonable easy and convenient.

Comment: Ctrl+End is the basic shortcut for any text editors

Comment: Is it in the menu? Just a shortcut is some kind of ugly I am afraid.

Answer (score 9):

If you open files from a shortcut or command line, you can add flags to specify the line number and column to place the cursor, e.g.

```
"notepad++.exe" -n12 -c34 license.txt
```

(note no spaces between -n/-c and line/column numbers).

To open the file at the bottom, use a very large line number, e.g.

```
"notepad++.exe" -n999999 filename
```

Comment: This goes to bottom indeed. But unfortunately it scrolls almost at the end of the file. This is odd.

Comment: Notepad++ (5.8.6 at least) has an annoying bug which scrolls to the physical line (as determined by newline characters) without taking into account the number of lines shown onscreen. If word wrap is enabled and any of the lines above this line wrap, it can be pushed offscreen, even though the cursor is at the right place.

Comment: Notepad++ 7.8.8 and perhaps some other older releases had a [bug with moving the cursor but not scrolling the viewport with word wrap enabled](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/8007). This is fixed in 7.9.

Answer (score 2):

You can not only see the updated file but also always shift to the updated line i.e. e.o.f. like in case of viewing logs.

`Settings -> Preferences -> MISC`

`Tick **Update silently**`

`Tick **scroll to the last line after update**.`

[image]

Comment: How does it work, as soon as I change a file, it moves to the end of file? No it does not.

Answer (score 1):

the Notepad++ has a superb useful command line parameter -monitor
You just start it in the prompt:

```
c:\> notepad++ -monitor d:/temp/monitor_me.log
```

It opens (or creates) a file, and starts probing it several times per second.
When it detects that the file was changed, it updates the screen with the changes and tries scrolling to the end.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It is discouraged to answer very old questions unless they have no answer or you have something substantial to add.  The questionner wanted to open a file with the insertion point at the end as opposed to the beginning. Similar to if they hit `CTRL`+`END` .   I don't understand how [your answer](https://superuser.com/a/1763850/) addresses that.  Please consider updating or removing your answer to avoid down votes but continue to contribute to the community.